# I have trouble using reDim in VBA, can't figure out how it works

Tags: arrays, string, excel, vba, function

I would like to write a function, where the input is a string (e.g. ACGTTGCATGTCGCATGATGCATGAGAGCT) and an integer (e.g. 4). The function should be able to identify the sub-string(s) with the length of the integer that are the most commonly repeated in the input string. I think I am supposed to use reDim, and although I have researched how it is supposed to work, I just cannot figure out the proper syntax.

> Code Challenge: Solve the Frequent Words Problem. Input: A string
>   Text and an integer k. Output: All most frequent k-mers in Text.

```
Function BIOINFO2(txt As String, k As Integer)


Dim FrequentPatterns As String
Dim ptrn As String
Dim n() As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim s As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim maxCount As Integer


For s = 1 To Len(txt) - k + 1
    ptrn = Mid(txt, s, k)
                For i = 1 To Len(txt) - Len(ptrn) + 1
                        If Mid(txt, i, Len(ptrn)) = ptrn Then
                        ReDim n(i)
                        n(i) = 0
                        n(i) = n(i) + 1
                        End If
                Next i
                maxCount = Application.Max(n(i))
        For j = 1 To Len(txt) - k + 1
            If n(i) = maxCount Then
               FrequentPatterns = FrequentPatterns + " " + Mid(txt, s, k)
            End If
        Next j
Next s

BIOINFO2 = FrequentPatterns

End Function
```

Comment: *Code Challenge*...? Starting to sound like homework.

Comment: I would not use `REDIM`, rather I would use a Collection object to initially collect, for example, all patterns that have a frequency of more than one (1).  Then go through the collection to identify the most frequent value, and return all those with that value.

Comment: Dictionaries are the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just to clarify the `ReDim` issue, not the logic of your code.

You use `ReDim` to resize an array (losing the values stored in it), `ReDim Preserve` to resize an array while keeping the values.

If you know the required size of your array beforehand, you should allocate it with the correct size at the start, as in

```
Dim arr(1 To m) As Long
```

If you don't know the required size, you can resize it later on like this

```
Dim arr() As Long
'Do stuff and find out you need the array to hold m elements
ReDim Preserve arr(1 To m)
```

Your case is somewhat in between because you know the size right at the start of your function but it is not a constant size. You can `Dim` an array with a specific size only if it's constant so in this case you need to declare it without bounds first and then `ReDim` with the correct size.

```
Dim arr() as Long
ReDim arr(1 To m) As Long
```

`Redim arr(m)` is the same as `Redim arr(base To m)` where `base` is either 0 or 1. The default value is 0 but you can set it using `Option Base 1` at the beginning of your module.

You can find out the highest and lowest array indices using the `UBound` and `LBound` functions so a loop that loops over all the values could look like this

```
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    'Do something
Next i
```

That way you avoid problems with different bases.

It is usually better to do as little resizing of arrays as possible. In the worst case scenario, the system has to copy the whole array to another location in the memory where there is enough free space.

Answer (score 1):

Just to show that VBA is not needed for a task like this:
(A1 would be your string and A2 the length)

```
=MID(A1,MATCH(MIN(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID(A1,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1)-A2+1)),A2),""))),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID(A1,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1)-A2+1)),A2),"")),0),A2)
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>!

At least to get the first possible solution.

Comment: to get them all: `=IFERROR(INDEX(INDEX(MID($A$1,(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN($A$1)-($C$2-1)))-1)+1,$C$2),),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN($A$1)-($C$2-1)))/(MAX((LEN($A$1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,INDEX(MID($A$1,(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN($A$1)-($C$2-1)))-1)+1,$C$2),),"")))/$C$2)=(LEN($A$1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,INDEX(MID($A$1,(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN($A$1)-($C$2-1)))-1)+1,$C$2),),"")))/$C$2),ROW(1:1))),"")`  My count is in C2.

Comment: I think this would depend on whether a word "ATAT" would count as occuring once or twice in "ATATAT" ?  Seems like using substitute would only count it once.